# How to detect certain special characters in perl string?

Tags: regex, perl, character

I want to detect the presence of certain characters like @ # $ % \ / in a Perl string. Can anyone suggest a regex for this. I tried few but it is not working.

```
=~ /(\W@\W#\W%\W*)/)
=~ /(@|#|%|*)/)
```

I tried these but it is not working.

Can anyone suggest where i am going wrong?

Comment: `=~m/\W/g;` It is enough.

Comment: I'm puzzled about what you thought the `\W` would do?

Answer (score 4):

You were on the right track with your second attempt, but you forgot to escape characters that have a special meaning in regex patterns.

```
/\@|#|\$|%|\\|\//       # or m{\@|#|\$|%|\\|/}
```

However, it would be more efficient to use a character class.

```
/[\@#\$%\\//]/          # or m{[\@#\$%\\/]}
```

If you're ok with checking for any non-word characters, you can use

```
/\W/
```

---

A safer approach is usually to specify the characters you want to allow, and exclude everything else. For example,

```
/[^\w]/           # Only allow word characters.
```

or

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/   # Only allow unaccented latin letters, "european" digits, and underscore.
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=~ /[@#$%\/]/
```

if one of the character is included in the string it will detected

```
my $s = "@";
if ($s =~ /[@#\$\%\/]/) {
        print "have it";
}
```

Comment: It is detecting only the first character. Try with # it will not work

Comment: $% is treated as a variable (interpolating '0'), and the backslash escapes the forward slash.  try `/[\@#\$%\\\/]/`

Comment: try this. It is not working at my end  

my $s = "lj2dm%";
if ($s =~ /[@#$%\/]/) {
        print "have it \n";
}

Comment: @dev_k2.0 The % sign must be escaped. See my edited answer

Comment: No, `%` doesn't need to be escaped, though there's no harm (except to readability) in escaping it. (I'm not the downvoter.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html). For example:

```
my $chars = '@#$%\/';
my ($regex) = map { qr /$_/ } join '|', map {quotemeta} split //, $chars;
```